# How to interact the parent url as React app inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Due to security issues, we need to wrap our React application inside an iFrame.

Let say the site url is **http://app.com**

When I type http://app.com/products/12,
It should transit to this route inside React app.
Similarly, if a user changes routes and the URL should also reflect the route state change.

Currently, I could render the React app inside iFrame. But URL and app route state are not interacting each other.

Any good practice suggested?

## Route.js

```
<Switch >
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => {}}/>
                <Route exact path="/products" render={() => {}}/>
                <Route exact path="/products/:id" render={() => {}}/>                
</Switch>
```

Comment: Is the perant application is also an react application?

Comment: No. It’s not react